# Wrap list into custom string based on the list

Tags: python, list

So I have a list that looks like the following:

```
 mylist = ['100003028593816', '1784394111', '100008137385157', '100000462582000','100001633550680', '100000757743079']
```

(This list can vary based on different inputs, etc. This is just an example)

I want to create a STRING from that array that looks like the following.

```
string = '{"100003028593816":1,"1784394111":1,"100008137385157":1,"100000462582000":1,"100001633550680":1,"100000757743079":1}'
```

(NOTE: See how they are the same values as above, they're just wrapped up differently. That's how they need to be posted. So I pretty much want to take the values from the array and wrap them as {"value1":1,"value2":1} etc.

Comment: This looks like JSON. Use `import json`. You can get your format from `collections.Counter(mylist)` (at least I'm assuming that's what the `1` values mean), then `json.dump(some_open_binary_fileobj)`

Comment: Yeah, it looks like json as well, but I need it to append the :1 after each value. So it needs to be "value_from_array":1, etc

Comment: Post the code you've tried to do this, You cant ask people to code for you by posting your problem definition

Answer (score 3):

Here's a somewhat unreadable way of doing that using list comprehension:

```py
'{%s}' % ','.join('"%s":1' % a for a in mylist)
```

Comment: great answer if order is important to him ... +1

Answer (score 1):

```
str(dict.fromkeys(mylist,1))
```

is nice ... but it will break your ordering (dicts have no order, however lists do)

Comment: I  think this should be str(dict.fromkeys(mylist).keys()) to avoid including the None values.

Comment: str(OrderedDict.fromkeys(mylist).keys()) preserves the order

Comment: yeah but thin it will print differently from how he wants (also i have 2.6 right now and OrderedDict is 2.7 )

Answer (score 1):

While I believe that you should first post the code which you have tried first and should not ask to spoonfeed, however, here's your answer, simple and understandable:

```
mylist = ['100003028593816', '1784394111', '100008137385157', '100000462582000','100001633550680', '100000757743079']
str='{'
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    str+='\"'+mylist[i]+'\":1,'
str=str[:-1]    #remove the last trailing comma
str+='}'
print str
```

Output:

```
{"100003028593816":1,"1784394111":1,"100008137385157":1,"100000462582000":1,"100001633550680":1,"100000757743079":1}
```

Comment: This answer is also `n^2`, which in python world means slow for arrays of even several thousand elements.

Comment: I agree with you, but by question's quality I assumed that he is new to python and can use some help with learning logics of programming instead of trying to understand best pythonic ways. Can you add more light on how its n^2?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing it using a lambda function:

```
'{' + ','.join(map(lambda x: '"' + x + '":1', mylist)) + '}'
```

Cheers!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "friendchunk.py", line 146, in <module>
    '{' + ','.join(map(lambda x: '"' + x + '":1', friends)) + '}'
  File "friendchunk.py", line 146, in <lambda>
    '{' + ','.join(map(lambda x: '"' + x + '":1', friends)) + '}'
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Comment: Of course, it only works with lists of strings. Otherwise you would need to convert it to string using str(x), like so:

`'{' + ','.join(map(lambda x: '"' + str(x) + '":1', mylist)) + '}'`

NoneTypes will be converted to the string `'None'`.

Answer (score 0):

**Converting Array to Dictionary Format**

Here's a solution that parses each index of the array and converts it into dict format:

```
string = "{\""
mylist = ['100003028593816', '1784394111', '100008137385157', '100000462582000','100001633550680', '100000757743079']

#The first n-1 array indicies
for i in range(len(mylist)-1):
    string += (mylist[i] + "\":1,\"")

#last array index with closing bracket
string += (mylist[len(mylist)-1] + "\":1}")
```

Here is the result:

```
>>> string
 '{"100003028593816":1,"1784394111":1,"100008137385157":1,"100000462582000":1,"100001633550680":1,"100000757743079":1}'
```

Note that the \" is so that we can print quotes inside strings, so the **\"**:1,**\"** will become ":1," and the last **\"**:1} will become ":1}.